# create a self signed certificate in iis in windows server 2012 R2

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I have tried to so many ways but is sys,
**Attackers might be trying to steal your information from mttnihar.com (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**

in my case, I have published my site in windows server 2012R2 ISS -> then in our office internal DNS server I have config domain with my server IP. HTTP its working fine but HTTPS:// not working.

I try to create a certificate in my windows server IIS but it's not solved my issue.
I need to implement all my internal staff can use with HTTPS(certified). Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The browser side error message is always there when you use a self-signed certificate on server side. Talk to your domain administrator/network administrator and learn how to get a valid internal certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error message when you are not using a trusted CA certificate. to resolve the issue you could try on of try below solution:

1)Click on the advanced button:

[image]

Click on the proceed to unsafe link:

[image]

Now you can work with the sell signed certificate.
This will only recommend when you are using sit internally. if you are hosting a site on internet it is recommended to use a trusted CA certificate.

or

2)ad the self-signed certificate to the browser ca store:

https://superuser.com/questions/947927/chrome-is-not-accepting-my-iis-self-signed-certificate